# Getting error while switching the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So there is `BottomNavigationView` when I am clicking on any item, a fragment should open. But end up getting the following error
Log:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.remove(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView) on a null object reference
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.java:2534)
at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:14392)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3108)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3105)
at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4472)
at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4445)
at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:4377)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1411)at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:753)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Fragment

```
 public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {



    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ProfileFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ProfileFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        return view;
    }
```

Switching is done as:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         transaction.replace(R.id.main_container_home, currFragment,currTag);
         transaction.commit();

      }
 });
```

any help will helpfull

**Solution Tried:**

1.Empty the fragment layout and set only relative layout with the empty child.Still Error.

The app crashes in onCreateView() of the fragment.

UpDate: finally got the root cause of crashes it is because I am adding view in container i.e container.add(view)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to switch between the fragments. You have to put NavigationBottomMenu inside the Activity, create as many fragments as the number of items in BottomNav, and then commit the fragments from there.

This is the **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
private SearchPropertyFragment searchPropertyFragment;
private ChatFragment chatFragment;
private ProfileFragment profileFragment;
private NotificationFragment notificationFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    searchPropertyFragment = new SearchPropertyFragment();
    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
    profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    notificationFragment = new NotificationFragment();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_frame, searchPropertyFragment).commit();

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationMenu) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id){
                case R.id.bottom_menu_properties:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, searchPropertyFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.bottom_menu_chat:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, chatFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.bottom_menu_profile:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, profileFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.bottom_menu_notifications:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, notificationFragment).commit();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is **activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/navigationItemBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/navigationItemIcon"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/navigationItemtext"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Define your fragments accordingly.

Hope This Helps.

Comment: I am doing in the same way. But using runOnUiThread that also I have removed but still getting the same error.

Comment: No need to do on a separate thread. It has to be done in UI thread only

Comment: Just remove the thread and do it inside bottomNav setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()